# ADODB VBA SQL Query for update

Tags: vba

I have a macro which update the MS Access file and then move the data from one table to another table. With the below coding, I am able to move the data from one table to another table but data is not getting updated.

`enter code here`Dim pdate As Date
With Acon
.Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"
.ConnectionString = "Data Source=" + myFileNameDir
.Properties("Jet OLEDB:Database Password") = "synpass"
.Open
End With

Issue is in this code

```
Set CMD = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
CMD.ActiveConnection = Acon
strSQL = "Update Detail set Trackerpulldate = pdate where [Overall status]= 'Completed'"
CMD.CommandText = strSQL
CMD.Execute
CMD.Save
```

Below code is running fine with proper output

```
On Error Resume Next
Set CMD2 = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
CMD2.ActiveConnection = Acon
strSQL2 = "INSERT INTO Updated_Tracker SELECT * From Detail where [Overall status]= 'Completed'"
CMD2.CommandText = strSQL2
CMD2.Execute

Acon.Close
Set Acon = Nothing
On Error GoTo 0
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming `pdate` is supposed to be a variable (containing a date)?!

```
"Update Detail set Trackerpulldate = pdate where [Overall status]= 'Completed'"
```

As it stands right now you are never actually referring to the variable `pdate` - I's just part of a string. You are basically trying to update `Trackerpulldate` to the value `pdate` not the value the variable `pdate` holds.

See the code below that removes all unnecessary code and shows the problem.

```
Dim pdate As Long
pdate = 10
Debug.Print "pdate"
```

Comment: yes.. pdate is date variable

Comment: @ZaidShaikh then this is the problem - you are not passing a value, you are passing the string `"pdate"`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Set CMD = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
CMD.ActiveConnection = Acon
strSQL = "Update Detail set Trackerpulldate = @pdate where [Overall status]= 'Completed'"
CMD.CommandText = strSQL
CMD.Parameters.Append CMD.CreateParameter("@pdate",adDate, adParamInput, , pdate)
CMD.Execute
CMD.Save
```

> why not just a simple string concatenation?

Formating `date` value for string concatenation in query text is provider or server specific, often causes errors on server side or ADODB provider.

Comment: why not just a simple string concatenation?  `"[...] Trackerpulldate = '" & Format(pdate, yyyy-mm-dd) & "' [...]"`

Comment: Million Thanks ValNik.. It is working properly. You are the best among the best.